# Navigate to new page in site, keep an element loaded?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, navigation, soundcloud

I have an `iframe` element that contains a music player via SoundCloud. When a user switches tabs, it reloads. Is there a way to load the new page in the background and keep the `iframe` as-is?

## Edit

I'm using Rails.

Answer (score 1):

[pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) might be what you're looking for.

This gem allows you to load pages in the background using ajax and reloads only the divs you really need